# how to reduce number of tab bar items shown on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a split View Controller iPad app.  Its a port of a iPhone version that relied heavily on the tab bar.  Since you cannot put a split view controller into a tab bar (or at least shouldn't, or so I've read) I settled on a design where the tabbar controller is inside the detail view controller of the split view controller.

This works fine.  However, the tabbar is showing 8 tabs rather than 5 like on the iPhone.  This makes for an incredibly cramped tab bar.

I know on the iPhone the 4+more is unchangable.  Does anyone know if there's a way to make the iPad only show 4 icons or 5 icons on the tabbar?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had wanted the same thing before. However, UITabBarController does not provide a way to control the number of tabs shown.

I would suggest using a navigation controller instead of the tab bar. Using similar-looking pretty icons at the left, a navigation-based interface goes well with the split view interface.

If the tab bar is really what you want, you may remove some of the tabs when it goes to the landscape mode, and add a custom 'more' tab instead. You can have a navigation-based table view there to show the removed items. It is even possible to implement 'edit' feature of UITabBarController's 'More' view, but I think it wouldn't be worth the effort.